# How to add more than one class on React JSX?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, webstorm

It works with one class only, but it won't compile with 2 or more classes declared.

```
function Logo() {
    return (
        <div className={logo}>
            <img src={logo} id={logo} className={logo second} alt={"..."}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Error:

```
  Line 21:55:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  19 |     return (
  20 |         <div className={logo}>
> 21 |             <img src={logo} id={logo} className={logo second} alt={"..."}/>
     |                                                       ^
  22 |         </div>
  23 |     );
  24 | }
```

Comment: they need to be strings.

Answer (score 1):

The `className` prop takes a single string, in the same way that the `class` attribute would in HTML.

It looks like both of your classes are stored in variables, so you can put them together like so (2 methods):

**Template Strings**

```
<img src={logo} id={logo} className={`${logo} ${second}`} alt={"..."}/>
```

**String Concatenation**

```
<img src={logo} id={logo} className={logo + " " + second} alt={"..."}/>
```

Comment: It's not the case, because they aren't variables.
I have changed into strings and it worked.

className="logo second"